# Adwords Script Error - Failed To Read From Adwords

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Hoping you can help. I'm quite new to using Javascript so apologies in advance if this is pretty basic!
I've been trying to implement Google's flexible budget script for Manager Accounts..
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/mccapp-flexible-budgets

I've set everything up but continually get the `Failed To Read From Adwords error on line 103...`:

```
var costSoFar = campaign.getStatsFor(
        dateToString(startDate),
        dateToString(endDate)
    ).getCost();
```

I've been using the single account version of this script fine. 
Would be good to know what I can do - or failing that the sort of troubleshooting checks I can make myself as I start to get my head around scripting.

Thanks in advance
Ed

Comment: Which dates ares you using? Could you print some variables before that line? Llike this:
Logger.log("CampaignName: "+campaign.getName());
Logger.log("startDate: "+startDate);
Logger.log("endDate: "+endDate);

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've got the following:                                 CampaignName: Brand - BM StartDate: Mon Dec 20 1915 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

Comment: thanks for this - just ran that and it came back with an issue on the start date, amended accoridngly and it all seems to work now! thanks for your help...the logger.log command seems ideal for troubleshooting. thanks again